# Dynamically expand selected option background

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The problem:
As you can see in the image, the **background of the selected option** does not expand as the width of the **option text**, and with a white background.. it will not show the remaining of the text, how can I fix this ?
I am using Chrome, but I want this in firefox and IE as well.

[image]

HTML:

```
<select multiple="" class="h-scrollable form-control">
                <option ng-repeat="elem in list">
                    {{elem}}</option>
            </select>
```

CSS:

```
.h-scrollable
{
    width: 350px; 
    height: 150px !important;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-right:20px;
    font-size: medium;
}
.h-scrollable:focus
{
    height: 150px !important;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-right:20px;
    font-size: medium;
    background-size: 100%;
    background: pink;
}
.h-scrollable option
{
    /*width: 350px; */
}
.h-scrollable option:checked
{
    /*width: 400px; THIS FIXES THE PROBLEM FOR A TEXT OF WIDTH = 350px; I want a general solution  that will work for any length of  text*/
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you're trying to do? Here is a fiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/n3g0gb97/

Comment: CSS and Dynamically don't necessarily mix all too well.  Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: post your generated markup in the question, not the angular code.

Comment: Your css works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/7dkhgLrv/ What exactly is your problem?

Comment: No it doesn't. Use CHROME, in firefox you don;st see the scrollbar, if you scroll to the right the background of the selected option won't be the same size as the text of that option.

Comment: The image I've posted is very self explanatory

Comment: It is working just fine in Chrome. If you are looking for cross browser consistency, then stop. You will never get that for this case. IE will just not give you scrollbars on select. Firefox will behave differently. You will end wasting lot of your productive time working it out in vain.

Comment: @abhitalks check this out, the second option, in chrome.http://jsfiddle.net/7dkhgLrv/4/

Comment: @A.K I think I understand what you're asking. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out why you're attempting what you're attempting. Surely the answer is a better design that does NOT need a scrollbar?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have a fixed width select control with unknown length of option text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the select inside of a div, removing widths on the select/option and adding a width and overflow: auto to the div.  http://jsfiddle.net/g52qmz32/

```
<div style="width: 240px; overflow: auto;">
    <select multiple="" class="h-scrollable form-control">
    <option>one option</option>
    <option>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
    <option>another option</option>
    <option>last option is really very long one</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It may need some revision to your liking, but I believe this is what you're after.

** edit: I removed the margin-right to eliminate the scrollbar if the content isn't wider than 240px.  Also added a min-width to the .h-scrollable class.  Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to do `text-overflow` and allow the text to be automatically truncated rather than needing a scrollbar.

It's up to the designer's discretion but personally I would think twice, then a third time before requiring a user to scroll inside a `select` field.

See this update of your fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7dkhgLrv/6/

UPDATE: also, add an `overflow: auto;` to the `.h-scrollable` class for best effect.